# How to set low at below high at top y axis with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to the python programming and I'm trying to create a timing diagram from the output of a logic gate. I'm using raspbian and the data is saved in csv. Any code to flip the y axis to make '0' on bottom and '1' on top? It's because if I get the data starting from '1', the graph will be '1' at bottom and '0' at top.

Here I give the example that '1' at the  bottom. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztWeX.jpg)

[image]

```
## the # in 2 row have some code##

from guizero import App,PushButton
from gpiozero import LED,Button
from time import sleep
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=LED(2)
b=LED(3)
c=LED(4)
d=LED(14)
E=Button(15,pull_up=False)
F=Button(17,pull_up=False)
G=Button(18,pull_up=False)
H=Button(27,pull_up=False)
I=Button(22,pull_up=False)
J=Button(23,pull_up=False)
K=Button(24,pull_up=False)
L=Button(10,pull_up=False)
M=Button(9,pull_up=False)
N=Button(25,pull_up=False)
O=Button(11,pull_up=False)
P=Button(8,pull_up=False)
Q=Button(7,pull_up=False)
R=Button(5,pull_up=False)
S=Button(6,pull_up=False)
T=Button(12,pull_up=False)
U=Button(13,pull_up=False)
V=Button(19,pull_up=False)
W=Button(16,pull_up=False)
X=Button(26,pull_up=False)
Y=Button(20,pull_up=False)
Z=Button(21,pull_up=False)
t=1/1000000

def nwln_csv():
    with open('hz.csv','w') as file:
        writer=csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["D","C","B","A","choice","choice_output","Z","Y","X","W","V","U","T","S","R","Q","P","O","N","M","L","K","J","I","H","G","F","E"])    
def nxtln_csv():
    print(d.value,c.value,b.value,a.value,choice.value,choice_output.value,Z.value,Y.value,X.value,W.value,V.value,U.value,T.value,S.value,R.value,Q.value,P.value,O.value,N.value,M.value,L.value,K.value,J.value,I.value,H.value,G.value,F.value,E.value)
    with open('hz.csv','a') as file:
        writer=csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([d.value,c.value,b.value,a.value,choice.value,choice_output.value,Z.value,Y.value,X.value,W.value,V.value,U.value,T.value,S.value,R.value,Q.value,P.value,O.value,N.value,M.value,L.value,K.value,J.value,I.value,H.value,G.value,F.value,E.value])           
#
#
def input_one():
    nwln_csv()
    d.off()
    c.off()
    b.off()
    a.off()
    sleep(t)
    nxtln_csv()
    a.on()
    sleep(t)
    nxtln_csv()
    d.off()
    c.off()
    b.off()
    a.off()
def input_two():
    nwln_csv()
    d.off()
    c.off()
    b.off()
    a.off()
    sleep(t)
    nxtln_csv()
    a.on()
    sleep(t)
    nxtln_csv()
    b.on()
    a.off()
    sleep(t)
    nxtln_csv()
    a.on()
    sleep(t)
    nxtln_csv()
    d.off()
    c.off()
    b.off()
    a.off() 
def plot_graph():
    def input1_outputz():
        fig,(axa,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input2_outputz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input3_outputz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axc,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=4,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axc.plot(c,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axc.set_ylabel('C',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input4_outputz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axc,axd,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=5,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axc.plot(c,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axc.set_ylabel('C',rotation=0)
        axd.plot(d,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axd.set_ylabel('D',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')

    def input1_outputyz():
        fig,(axa,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z,rotation=0')
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input2_outputyz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=4,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input3_outputyz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axc,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=5,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axc.plot(c,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axc.set_ylabel('C',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input4_outputyz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axc,axd,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=6,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axc.plot(c,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axc.set_ylabel('C',rotation=0)
        axd.plot(d,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axd.set_ylabel('D',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')

    def input1_outputxz():
        fig,(axa,axx,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=4,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axx.plot(x,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axx.set_ylabel('X',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z,rotation=0')
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input2_outputxz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axx,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=5,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axx.plot(x,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axx.set_ylabel('X',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input3_outputxz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axc,axx,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=6,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axc.plot(c,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axc.set_ylabel('C',rotation=0)
        axx.plot(x,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axx.set_ylabel('X',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
    def input4_outputxz():
        fig,(axa,axb,axc,axd,axx,axy,axz)=plt.subplots(nrows=7,ncols=1,sharex=True)
        axa.set_title('TIMING DIAGRAM')
        axa.plot(a,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axa.set_ylabel('A',rotation=0)
        axb.plot(b,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axb.set_ylabel('B',rotation=0)
        axc.plot(c,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axc.set_ylabel('C',rotation=0)
        axd.plot(d,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='lime')
        axd.set_ylabel('D',rotation=0)
        axx.plot(x,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axx.set_ylabel('X',rotation=0)
        axy.plot(y,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='plum')
        axy.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
        axz.plot(z,drawstyle='steps-pre',color='red')
        axz.set_ylabel('Z',rotation=0)
        axz.set_xlabel('x axis')
#
#

    d=[]
#
#
    x=[]
    y=[]
    z=[]
    with open("hz.csv","r") as file:
        reader=csv.reader(file)
        next(file)
        for row in reader:
            d.append(row[0])
            c.append(row[1])
            b.append(row[2])
            a.append(row[3])
            z.append(row[6])
            y.append(row[7])
            x.append(row[8])
#
#
    if choice.value=='1' and choice_output.value=='Z':
        input1_outputz()
    if choice.value=='2' and choice_output.value=='Z':
        input2_outputz()
    if choice.value=='3' and choice_output.value=='Z':
        input3_outputz()
    if choice.value=='4' and choice_output.value=='Z':
        input4_outputz()
    if choice.value=='1' and choice_output.value=='Y-Z':
        input1_outputyz()
    if choice.value=='2' and choice_output.value=='Y-Z':
        input2_outputyz()
    if choice.value=='3' and choice_output.value=='Y-Z':
        input3_outputyz()
    if choice.value=='4' and choice_output.value=='Y-Z':
        input4_outputyz()
    if choice.value=='1' and choice_output.value=='X-Z':
        input1_outputxz()
    if choice.value=='2' and choice_output.value=='X-Z':
        input2_outputxz()
    if choice.value=='3' and choice_output.value=='X-Z':
        input3_outputxz()
    if choice.value=='4' and choice_output.value=='X-Z':
        input4_outputxz()
#
#
    plt.show()

app=App(title='LITAR LGOGIKA 2.0',width=800,height=480,layout="grid")
#
#
b_generate=PushButton (app,command=plot_graph,text="GENERATE GRAPH",grid=[2,5])
app.display()
```

Comment: `plt.ylim(1, 0)` would reverse the y-axis with 0 at the top and 1 at the bottom. `plt.ylim(0, 1)` would have it the standard way.  If you'd add your code to the post, it would be easier to know what's going on. Also be careful that strings containing numbers need to be converted to numbers.

Comment: My total code almost 4000 line I afraid it will hard so check. But can this ylim work on subplot

Comment: Please don't post your whole code. Only a small part that demonstrates the problem in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `invert_yaxis()` to flip any yaxis like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Or you can try to manually set the y ticks like this:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks([0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Or you can try to manually set the y limits like this:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

If you are using subplots, any of these options can be used in a similar way. You probably don't need to use them all for the same plot, but this is how they could be applied:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_yticks([0, 1])
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can this use to subplot?

Comment: yes, I added an example of how you'd use them for subplots.

Comment: have update some coding for references. which hope u can help me. i already try all three suggestion but only plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  can manage but also t only work for the last subplot not all subplot. hope u can assist me more. thanks

Comment: After every line where you have `axz.plot(...)`, try adding the line `axz.set_ylim(0, 1)` or `axz.invert_yaxis()`